# Facebook graph API: nested query

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to perform a nested query to facebook graph API to retrive both page data and page likes (i.e., pages liked by the page) through the same call.

Here is the query for page data:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/nytimes?fields=name,about,likes,website,description,category,cover,emails,general_info,username,talking_about_count
```

it returns output 1:

```
{
   "name": "The New York Times",
   "about": "Welcome to The New York Times on Facebook - a hub for conversation about news and ideas. Like our page and connect with Times journalists and readers. ",
   "likes": 10724374,
   "website": "www.nytimes.com www.twitter.com/nytimes www.youtube.com/nytimes",
   "category": "Media/News/Publishing",
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "10150582560169999",
      "offset_x": 0,
      "offset_y": 0,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/s720x720/11262391_10150582560169999_4778921193093539141_o.jpg",
      "id": "10150582560169999"
   },
   "emails": [
      "help\u0040nytimes.com"
   ],
   "username": "nytimes",
   "talking_about_count": 852257,
   "id": "5281959998"
}
```

Here is the query for page likes:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/nytimes/likes
```

it returns output 2:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Sheri Fink",
         "id": "161972884003991"
      },
      {
         "name": "The New York Times Books",
         "id": "1002391179791389"
      },
      {
         "name": "The New York Times Styles",
         "id": "993603507345855"
      },
      ...
```

Is there a way to perform those two queries in a unique call using [nested requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading) to get output 2 nested in output 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I unfortunately don't think this is possible, because this is an ambiguity in the Graph API. I opened a bug about this a few months ago, have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1068883066456102/

Comment: ok Tobi, I was guessing there was a problem in names of edges and fields. So the only thing we can do it is to wait for fix in 2.6. Looking forward for next version :(